# Is there a built-in command like `\sin` except for curl?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, italic, vector

I know that we can write `\sin x` to get a non-italic sin. I would have expected there to be a similar command for curl, so I could write `\curl \mathbf{F}`. Is there such a command, or should I define my own?

Also, this really seems like a question for Google/a manual, but after making quite a few searches all I could find was information on how to format `\nabla \times \mathbf{F}`. Am I looking wrong or is this just something no one is interested in?

Comment: If you load `amsmath` you can do `\DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{curl}`; it would be almost impossible to predefine all operator names. For the cross product, use `\times`.

Comment: You should define your own, and the linked question shows how. Maybe not this one, but there are packages that define additional operators, so the one you need *might* be defined; `curl` is not defined in the kernel.